# Permuting k elements out of n

Tags: proof-writing, permutations, induction

I would like to prove the formula for choosing $k$ elements out of $n$ and permuting them. I have been able to prove this by simple logic, as in there are n choices of items to place in the first position, $n-1$ choices for the second position, all the way to $(n - k + 1)$ choices for the last space.

If I wished to prove this by induction, would I need to manipulate both the variables, $n$ and $k$? Or is it possible to perform this proof by assuming $k$ is always some value less than or equal to n, or in the inductive case, equal or less than $n + 1$?

Comment: First suppose $n$ is fixed, and induct on $k$. Then induct on $n$, using/proving "Pascal's Formula" to do the induction.

Comment: $k$ cannot exceed $n$ (or $n+1$ in the inductive step); since the notion of picking more than $n$ elements out of $n$ would involve  taking multisets and their permutations, which is a lot more complicated than simple permutations of distinct elements.

Comment: @Akay I have succesfully been able to show the steps when inducting on $k$.  However, I run into a bit of trouble when attempting to induct on $n$.  I  have been trying to use pascals identity, or prove it, but I am not exactly sure what the inductive step would be.